# ssh X forwarding doesn't work

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have ssh access to two non-local Ubuntu servers. I use an Ubuntu laptop to connect to these servers. Unfortunately X11 forwarding works on one of them, but not on the other.

Server1 (running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS): If I use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` to access the server, everything works nicely. The DISPLAY environment on the remote host gets set to localhost:10.0, and running `xclock` works perfectly.

Server2 (running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS): If I use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` to access the server, the DISPLAY environment does not get set on the remote host, and running `xclock -display localhost:10.0` results in the message `Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0`.

How can I debug/solve this problem? I don't know where to start.

Comment: do you have Xorg properly installed on the Server2? Does the xclock and DE work locally there?

Comment: Thank you, @Jakuje. There was a problem in the installation. xauth was not installed on server 2. (If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll acknowledge it as the answer to this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have X11 forwarding working, you need to have `xauth` installed on the remove server. Verify it is there. There should probably be also some guide in the server error log, complaining about missing executable or so.

Comment: There's no reason to have Xorg installed on the remote server.  Xauth is definitely required for X forwarding through ssh.